# Understanding ACL in Hyperledger Fabric v1.3

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, access-control

I was trying to understand ACL in Hyperledger Fabric v1.3. I read `configtx.yaml` and I saw the `channel` section described below:

```
Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Channel policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        # Who may invoke the 'Deliver' API
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        # Who may invoke the 'Broadcast' API
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        # By default, who may modify elements at this config level
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
```

As per documentation it is mentioned for `Readers` `# Who may invoke the 'Deliver' API` and for `Writers` `# Who may invoke the 'Broadcast' API`. I am not able to understand what `Deliver API` and what `Broadcast API` do.

Please let me know if anyone know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordering service nodes implement two APIs:

- Broadcast - the API for submitting transactions to the orderer
- Deliver - the API for receiving blocks from the orderer

Typically clients use the broadcast API and peer nodes use the deliver API.
Separating the policies allows you to permit certain clients / apps to only submit transactions but not be able to actually receive blocks and vice versa - peers would be able to consume blocks but not be able to submit transactions to the orderer.